# level set implementation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have a question about level-set implementation.

In the article "Distance Regularized Level Set Evolution and Its Application to Image Segmentation" Chunming Li, Chenyang Xu you can find a diffusion equation:

(sorry, but i'm not allowed to post images :( )

(14) page 4 from pdf

For dp(s) = 1-1/s the implementation is [MATLAB]:

```
distRegTerm = 4*del2(phi)-curvature;
```

where:

```
[phi_x,phi_y]=gradient(phi); 
s=sqrt(phi_x.^2 + phi_y.^2);
smallNumber=1e-10;  
Nx=phi_x./(s+smallNumber);
Ny=phi_y./(s+smallNumber);
curvature=div(Nx,Ny);
```

and it is OK, because for that dp the equation is (15)

I don't understand why for (10)

where:

p(s) is (16)

the code is:

```
distRegTerm=distReg_p2(phi);
```

where:

```
function f = distReg_p2(phi)
[phi_x,phi_y]=gradient(phi);
s=sqrt(phi_x.^2 + phi_y.^2);
a=(s>=0) & (s<=1);
b=(s>1);
ps=a.*sin(2*pi*s)/(2*pi)+b.*(s-1);
dps=((ps~=0).*ps+(ps==0))./((s~=0).*s+(s==0));
f = div(dps.*phi_x - phi_x, dps.*phi_y - phi_y) + 4*del2(phi);
```

I don't understand the last line of this function.

Thanks

Comment: Try asking on Computational Science Exchange or on Signal Processing.